# Last column in header is shifted when horizontal and vertical bar is appeared

Tags: jqgrid

Please take a look at first image. Here everything is ok
[image]

But when we move horizontal scroll to the right header is shifted. This only happened when  vertical scroll is appeared.

[image]

It's because of header width less than content width and I can fix it if I add 20px to the last header cell. But are there other solutions?

**UPDATE 1**:

```
createExpensesGrid: function (containerId) {
    var gridDefinition = window['personalExpensesGridModel'];
    var grid = $("#" + containerId);

    if (gridDefinition) {
        var buildKey = function (key) {
            return gridDefinition.gridid + key;
        };


        $.extend(gridDefinition, {
            loadComplete: function () {
                var selectedGuidRow = $('#TransId').val();
                if (selectedGuidRow) {
                    $(this).setSelection(selectedGuidRow, true);
                }

                $(this)
                    .find('.notes')
                    .each(function () {
                        $(this).tipsy();
                    });

                validateGrid($(this));

                // To prevent grid from being focused on tab
                $(this).removeAttr("tabindex");
                $(this).find("*[tabindex]").removeAttr("tabindex");
            }
        });

    }

    grid.jqGrid(gridDefinition);

}
```

Comment: You should post JavaScript code which you used to create jqGrid. Additionally it's important to know which versions of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI you use.

Comment: I use jquery 1.7.2, jquery ui 1.8.22 and jqGrid  4.4.1. Source was updated in **UPDATE1**

Comment: Sorry but you posted almost no code which could explain what you do and which jqGrid options and callbacks you use. The posted code can be reduced to `$("#" + containerId).jqGrid(gridDefinition);` which gives absolutely no information.